# How do I stop a jquery animation after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery animation that creates [fireworks](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Canvas-Based-Fireworks.html). To use it, you have to call it like this: $('SELECTOR').fireworks();

For "SELECTOR", I used html so it makes fireworks on the whole page. Now the problem is, I can't click anything anymore when this animation plays. I have an a tag, but I can't click it because the animation is running.

Is there anyway to stop the animation or a way for me to click the button when the animation is running?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried adding a listener event on click to stop the animation or setting a timer on the function?

Comment: The function isn't mine, so I don't really know how it works. Therefore, I'm not sure how to set a timer on the function.

Comment: Do you have another function that stops fireworks ?

Comment: Holy CPU intensive plugin..

Comment: [Check this short answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488203/how-do-i-stop-a-jquery-animation-after-x-seconds/37488447#37488447)

Comment: Interestingly, the plugin also reveals that it's based on a fiddle, which may prove fun to mess around with:  http://jsfiddle.net/dtrooper/AceJJ/

Comment: sounds like the injected canvas covers your page. Can't you inject it at the beginning of the html, so it's down in the stack? Or put it in a screen covering div with a lower z-index than the rest of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('SELECTOR').fireworks('destroy');
```

will turn it off

You can turn this off via a button by typing

```
<button onclick="TurnFireworksOff">Try it</button>
function TurnFireworksOff()
{
$('SELECTOR').fireworks('destroy'); 
}
```

Or automatically via timer by

```
setTimeout(TurnFireworksOff, 3000)
function TurnFireworksOff()
{
$('SELECTOR').fireworks('destroy'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, this is more than a "jquery animation".  It is literally drawing a canvas over, in your case since you used the HTML as your selector, your entire html page.  If you'd like to click something, leave a bit of your page un-fireworked instead of using the entire HTML.

To remove the fireworks, the code exposes a function called destroy which will allow you to remove the fireworks using a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), a [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), or whatever you'd like.

```
//taken from fireworks.js source
'destroy': function(element) {
    var jqe = $(element);

    // Check this element isn't already inited
    if (jqe.data('fireworks_data') === undefined) {
        console.log('Looks like this element is not yet inited!');
        return;
    }
    var data = jqe.data('fireworks_data');
    jqe.removeData('fireworks_data');

    // Stop the interval
    clearInterval(data.interval);

    // Remove the canvas
    data.canvas.remove();

    // Reset the elements positioning
    data.element.style.position = '';
}
```

You can invoke it like this

```
$('SELECTOR').fireworks('destroy')
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

           // Start Fireworks
           $('SELECTOR').fireworks();

           //Stop Fireworks after x milliseconds.
           x = 5000; 
           setTimeout(function() {$('SELECTOR').fireworks();}, x);
 });
```